# How should two elements be handled in React if they are simultaneously attempting to access and update the state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two elements that share the same state. I want to make changes in one element that need to be reflected in another element, and vice versa. My current code is not allowing me to run and is not throwing any errors. Please help me fix the issue. Below is the code for your review.

**Rendering component:**

```
<Editors name={"Hello"} />
```

**Actual Component:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export interface IName {
  name: string;
}

function Editors(props: IName) {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    setName(props.name);
  }, [props, name]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <input value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
      </div>

      <br />

      <div>
        <textarea
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        ></textarea>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Editors;
```

stackblitz link to see in action https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-daok8m?file=Editors.tsx,App.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing name from the useEffect dependence should do the trick

```
useEffect(() => {
  setName(props.name);
}, [props]);
```